# Is it safe to use images.get_serving_url_async() inside a ndb tasklet?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

NDB tasklets and `yield` are a great way to do async/parallel code. However, it is not quite clear from the documentation if this mecanism can be safely used with non-ndb async functions such as `images.get_serving_url_async()`.

The [NDB Asynchronous Operation documentation page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#urlfetch) has a very tiny section about using the NDB context's own version of `urlfetch_async()`, where it is stated (emphasis mine):

> The URL Fetch service has its own asynchronous request API. *It's fine, but not always easy to use with NDB tasklets*.

It is not quite clear to me why it is "not always easy to use with NDB tasklets", and this makes me wonder if the same statement applies to `images.get_serving_url_async()`.

So my question is: will I get into trouble if I do this?

```py
@ndb.tasklet
def foo():
    url = yield images.get_serving_url_async(image_key)
```

Comment: According to this rejected feature request, it looks like I could just `yield` the returned RPC object returned by `get_serving_url_async()`. http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=151

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine. The yield will wait for the RPC and allow other tasklets to run while waiting. The comment about urlfetch was just about its clumsy API.