# Error serving images asynchronously from blobstore using get_serving_url_async

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, asynchronous, blobstore

Im trying to get the url of an image from the blogstore. In using webapp2 and python.

I do this:

`from google.appengine.api.images import get_serving_url_async
...
upload = self.get_uploads()[0]
blob_key = upload.key()
url = yield get_serving_url_async(blob_key, secure_url = True)`

And I get the error message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1522,
> in __call__
> 
>     return response(environ, start_response)
> 
> TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
> 
> ERROR    2016-04-29 20:02:28,489 wsgi.py:279] 
> 
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line
> 267, in Handle
> 
>     result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1524,
> in __call__
> 
>     return self._internal_error(e)(environ, start_response)
> 
>   File "C:\Program Files
> (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1522,
> in __call__
> 
>     return response(environ, start_response)
> 
> TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

All is working fine when I use:

```
url = get_serving_url(blob_key, secure_url = True)
```

I don't find the way to obtain the url for an async download.

Does anybody know where is the error? There is very little in the web about how works.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of `python` are you using? and can you try `yield from` instead?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: how are you using `url`?

Comment: I mean you're aware that `get_serving_url(blob_key, secure_url = True)` is equivalent to `get_serving_url_async(blob_key, secure_url = True).get_results()`, not to `get_serving_url_async(blob_key, secure_url = True)`, right?

Comment: I've tried 'get_serving_url_async(blob_key, secure_url = True).get_results()'  but I get 'Error: UserRPC object has no attribute get_results'

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have said `equivalent`, I just meant to illustrate that there is some additional work to do when using the async version of the call. You'll need to dig out the exact details :) And it was indeed a typo, it should be `.get_result()`, see: the actual `get_serving_url()` implementation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/api/images

Comment: BTW, I *think* your expectation *may* need an adjustment: the async call just produces the download url in an async manner, it doesn't actually provide an 'url for an async download'. This might shed more light about its typical use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837590/is-it-safe-to-use-images-get-serving-url-async-inside-a-ndb-tasklet

Comment: Ups! You're right. I was thinking about async serving not async getting urls. I guess I've misunderstood this function. Thank you very much for your help Dan.